add new rules at runtime with Rule Unit API
IS'm trying to switch to a new set of rules at runtime. Is it possible to implement that with Rule Unit API and without using KIE API?
Current documentation states "Previous sections in this chapter explained traditional KIE APIs to use Drools rule engine. However, as introduced in First Rule Project, Rule Unit is a new and recommended style for implementing rules in Drools 8." but I was not able to find any solutions on to how to do it with Rule Unit API. Test projects using KIE do not using rule Unit data and I myself was not able to make them work.
My attempts
Rules.drl (to emulate the new file simply remove "test_rule_2" from the file
package rulesAndScenarios.services.ruleDrools;

unit TestRuleUnit;

import rulesAndScenarios.models.drools.*;

rule "test_rule_1"
    when
        /simpleObjects
    then
        System.out.println("test_rule_1 triggered");
end

rule "test_rule_2"
    when
        /simpleObjects
    then
        System.out.println("test_rule_2 triggered");
end

Rule Unit (TestRuleUnit):
package rulesAndScenarios.services.ruleDrools;

import org.drools.ruleunits.api.DataSource;
import org.drools.ruleunits.api.DataStore;
import org.drools.ruleunits.api.RuleUnitData;

public class TestRuleUnit implements RuleUnitData {

    private final DataStore<String> simpleObjects;

    public TestRuleUnit() {
        this(DataSource.createStore());
    }

    public TestRuleUnit(DataStore<String> simpleObjects) {
        this.simpleObjects = simpleObjects;
    }

    public DataStore<String> getSimpleObjects() {
        return simpleObjects;
    }
}

What I've tried doing:
1. Creating two instances and adding new file to a directory:
Test:
    public void testSimpleRule() throws Exception {
        TestRuleUnit testRuleUnit = new TestRuleUnit();
        testRuleUnit.getSimpleObjects().add("test_1");
        RuleUnitInstance<TestRuleUnit> instance = RuleUnitProvider.get().createRuleUnitInstance(testRuleUnit);
        try {
            instance.fire();
        } finally {
            instance.close();
        }
        Files.move(Paths.get("C:/Java folder/testRules2.drl"), Paths.get("C:/Users/aleks/my-project/target/classes/testRules.drl"), StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);

        TestRuleUnit testRuleUnit2 = new TestRuleUnit();
        testRuleUnit2.getSimpleObjects().add("test_1");
        RuleUnitInstance<TestRuleUnit> instance2 = RuleUnitProvider.get().createRuleUnitInstance(testRuleUnit);
        try {
            instance2.fire();
        } finally {
            instance2.close();
        }
    }

With the following test despite creating a new instance and providing new file, the instance is still checked against previous set of rules.
2. Apadpting existing test projects with KIE APIs with the usage of rule unit API but was not able to make the rules work - there were no errors but at the same time nothing was triggered. Rules themselves are correct which I've checked with a simple test without KIE sessions. The project in question - https://www.baeldung.com/drools.
3. Researching open sources about the problem. Found the following thread https://groups.google.com/g/drools-usage/c/G6A3EMbec90 but cant comprehend how method invalidateRuleUnits should be used, could not find documentation on Drools portals outside this single thread and provided links. Not even sure if it is what I need

As of now I've resigned to try and implement this with RuleUnit API.
Went back to traditional syntax and the usage of Kie.
Here is a solution for anyone interested:
@Component("FirstKieContainerConfigurationImpl")
public class FirstKieContainerConfigurationImpl implements KieContainerConfiguration {

    private KieContainer kieContainer;

    @Override
    public synchronized KieContainer getKieContainer() {
        if (kieContainer == null) {
            KieServices kieServices = KieServices.Factory.get();
            KieFileSystem kfs = kieServices.newKieFileSystem();

            File ruleFile = new File("path_to_rules/TAXI_FARE_RULE.drl");
            kfs.write(ResourceFactory.newFileResource(ruleFile));

            KieBuilder kieBuilder = kieServices.newKieBuilder(kfs);
            kieBuilder.buildAll();

            if (kieBuilder.getResults().hasMessages(Message.Level.ERROR)) {
                throw new RuntimeException("Errors while building KieModule: " + kieBuilder.getResults().getMessages());
            }

            KieModule kieModule = kieBuilder.getKieModule();
            kieContainer = kieServices.newKieContainer(kieModule.getReleaseId());
        }
        return kieContainer;
    }

    @Override
    public void rebuildKieContainer() {
        kieContainer = null;
        kieContainer = getKieContainer();
    }
}


getKieContainer() to create a KieContainer, which later used to start new session and fire rules
rebuildKieContainer() is invoked once I've updated rules in the directory.

The suggested implementation works and satisfies my requirements, but there is a strange interaction that I see in logs messages about creating KieBase - I expected to get this message after "rebuilding" as well, but it only happens when I call getKieContainer() directly in my screening.
Can't consider it an answer to the first question but if someone will find this useful - great.
